# "Change value" action in Views Bulk Operations?

Tags: views, 10

I'm moving from D7 to D10. One of my favourite and much needed things in D7 was "Change value" action in the VBO administration view. It was quite efficient way to editing many nodes at once.

I think I have checked everything here in D10 and I haven't found any easy solution.

Could you help me, please? Thanks!

Drupal core 10.2.0
Views Bulk Operations (VBO) 4.2.5

Szy.

Answer (score 1):

Almost immediately after posting I've found the module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_edit